# How is this array recording occurrences of each digit of input?

Tags: c, arrays, ascii

I am learning C using the K&R book, and came across a program that shows the use of arrays. The program uses an array to record the occurrences of each digit(number) entered, rather than having individual numbers stored(or so I think). Other than this, the program counts whitespaces and other characters. Here is the program -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
   // printf("Hello, World!\n");

    int c,i,nwhite,nother;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite=nother=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        ndigit[i]=0;

    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF)
        if (c>='0' && c<='9') 
        {
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        }
        else if(c==' '||c=='\n'||c=='\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
        ++nother;
    printf("digits = ");
    for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
        printf("%d", ndigit[i]);
    printf("\n white space= %d, other=%d\n", nwhite,nother);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is a sample output-

```
my birthday was 08081980
hello
digits = 3100000031
 white space= 5, other=18
```

It took me a while to figure out that the `ndigit` array records number of times each digit occurs. Example- `0` occurs 3 times in my input.

However, I couldn't figure out how the array was set through the loop. At the beginning,

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        ndigit[i]=0;
```

this for loop sets every element of the `ndigit` array to zero. But then, I didn't understand what happens in this if statement-

```
if (c>='0' && c<='9') {
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        }
```

That maybe due to the fact that I haven't come across this type of code before. What is the `++ndigit[c-'0']` expression trying to do? Does this assume that every digit entered is in the form of a character and then converted internally to an int through its ASCII value? What is the `c -'0'` expression doing here?

Many Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember that character constants are considered values of type `int` in C. In particular, they are integer values.

In any case, it is guaranted by the standard that typical characters, like english alphabetical letters, or digits, have all positive integer values, in the range of values of `char`.
Moreover, for any encoding schema of characters, **it is guaranted (by the standard C) that the digits '0' to '9' have contiguous codes**. For example, in the typical case of ASCII, we would have:

```
  '0' == 48  
  '1' == 49
  ...
  '9' == 57
```

Now, the sentence `if (c>='0' && c<='9')` is "asking" if the value of `c` is in the range of digits.
Then, the expressión `c - '0'` gives you the integer value of the digit, as it is easy to check.
For example, if `c == '3'`, we would have '3' - '0' == 51 - 48 == 3.

This is important, because the index of any array starts at 0 and, in the program, the array `ndigit` is intended to hold information of the j-th digit in the j-th position of the array.
So, the expressión `ndigit[ '3' - '0' ]` is the same as `ndigit[3]`.

Finally, to make a "count", we need to increment in 1 the value stored in `ndigit[3]`, so an increment operation is done, which is achieved through the `++` operator.

Answer (score 3):

`c-'0'` gives the numeric value corresponding to the character in `c`. It does this by subtracting the value of the `'0'` character from the value in `c`. This works because in most character schemes, the digits are given consecutive numeric codes (for example, in ASCII, the digits `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` are given the numeric code values `48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57`).

`ndigit[n]` gets the `n`th value of `ndigit`. Since `n` in this case it `c-'0'`, it gives the element of `ndigit` corresponding to the numeric value represented by `c`.

`++expr` increments (that is, increases by 1) the value referred to by `expr`. In this case, `expr` is the element in the array corresponding to the numeric value of `c`.